# finding and assigning substring

Tags: xml, regex, xslt, xpath, xslt-2.0

I have a string that may contain 'frontmatter'  or 'bodymatter', one of the two, like this
"chapter bodymatter"
"frontmatter toc"

I need the 'x-matter' substrings, to put it  elsewhere in an attribute.

I thought this would be nice, using an XPath expression:

```
 <xsl:variable name="front" select="substring( document(concat(tokenize(@href, '\.')[1],'.xml'))//section/@epub:type, '{[a-z]*matter}')"/>
```

The document part of the expression works nicely, but the substring function is the wrong way to go, and the XPath/RegExpr expression does not work like this in XSLT either.
I probably just need some XPath/RegExpr expression.
How could I do something like this?

Answer (score 2):

Found a solution. XSLT 2.0 has more facilities than met my eye:

```
<xsl:analyze-string select="document(concat(tokenize(@href, '\.')[1],'.xml'))//section/@epub:type" regex="([a-z]*)matter">
<xsl:matching-substring>
  <xsl:attribute name="epub:type"><xsl:value-of select="regex-group(1)"/>matter</xsl:attribute>
</xsl:matching-substring>
</xsl:analyze-string>
```

does the trick elegantly.
This shows also, what good a short lunch break and a bit of fresh air can do.

Comment: Even simpler: `<xsl:attribute name="epub:type" select="." />` - in XSLT 2.0 you can use `select` directly on an `xsl:attribute` instead of using nested content, and within `matching-substring` you can use `.` to refer to the whole substring that the regex matched (which in this case will include the "matter").